# Issue with: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach"

Tags: php, foreach, reporting, warnings

I'm having some woes with the above stated warning on an array.

I completely understand what the warning is, and what causes it, and I have taken every step I can to prevent it, but alas, none are having any effect.

**Steps taken:**

I have Checked for the array, declared it if not exists.

```
if(!$this->theVariables['associated']){
    $this->theVariables['associated'] = array();
   }
```

and

```
$this->theVariables['associated'] = $this->theVariables['associated'] || array();
```

Neither have any effect.

I have wrapped the `foreach` in an `if` that checks the array is not empty (`!empty()`), that it exists, that it is an array (`is_array()`), and then even type cast the array in the `foreach` declaration (`foreach((array)$this->theVariables['associated'] as $item)`) yet I am still getting this Warning.

As I have no way of switching error reporting off on this specific server, is there no other way of stopping this warning from displaying?

It is driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you var_dump the variable you are using and post the result here?

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the correct array? Or that it doesn't get overwritten inside the loop?

Comment: `var_dump` before I check for the array returns `null`, `var_dump` after I check and declare it returns `array(empty)` as expected. So the object is now an array, yet I still get this warning every time I try a `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
if (is_array($this->theVariables['associated'])) {
  // your foreach here
}
```

bacause for example if

`$this->theVariables['associated']` would be `1` this array assignment would never be reached:

```
if(!$this->theVariables['associated']){
    $this->theVariables['associated'] = array();
}
```

(The same goes for your second test)

As for Ólafur Waages comment, have a look at [Lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

For example, if your test looked something like this, you'll probably get problems:

```
<?php
$fakeArray = 'bad';

if (empty($fakeArray) && !is_array($fakeArray)) {
    $fakeArray = array();
}

var_dump($fakeArray);
```

**Output**:

```
string(3) "bad"
```

Comment: @Ólafur Waage as there is no example code of his testing with `is_array` I can only guess he is running into an lazy evaluation problem. (for example using an `!is_empty(...) ||` before the `is_array` check)

Comment: @Designermonkey Then please supply the code you tried (or better, the complete code). As `is_array` is normally foolproof.

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct as I can't retract the question. Our server wasn't reflecting the changes made in the code on each deployment of said code. I have just thoroughly gone through the code on the server to find that none of my edits had been applied.

Answer (score 0):

Why just didn't check with `if (is_array($this->theVariables['associated'])){`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to loop through that object, cast it as an array first:

```
foreach((array) $this->theVariable as $key => $value){
     echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$this->theVariables['associated'])
```

is **not** checking whether the array exists.

Write this instead:

```
if (!isset($this->theVariables['associated']) ||
   !is_array($this->theVariables['associated']))
```